# Configuring EnvoyFilter in Istio for "set_current_client_cert_details"

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

I have a scenario where I am terminating the TLS traffic at my Istio Ingress Gateway and forwarding it to respective services. Also have mTls and ISTIO_MUTUAL set. I need to validate the client certificate that is being sent when calling our Ingress-Gateway in the cluster and I am planning to do it in code for which I need the entire cert forwarded to my service code.

I tried configuring the EnvoyFilter as below :

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: xfcc-forward
  namespace: xfcc
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
    match:
      context: GATEWAY
      listener:
        filterChain:
          sni: "*"
    patch:
      operation: MERGE
      value:
        set_current_client_cert_details:
            cert: true
```

This fails while applying and I guess it might be because I am not configuring it right. Could someone help me with the right configuration of the EF for my scenario.

Answer (score 3):

I think I got the Configuration working with this :

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: xfcc-forward
  namespace: xfcc
spec:
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: NETWORK_FILTER
    match:
      context: GATEWAY
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.http_connection_manager"
    patch:
      operation: MERGE
      value:
        typed_config:
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.network.http_connection_manager.v2.HttpConnectionManager"
          forward_client_cert_details: ALWAYS_FORWARD_ONLY
          set_current_client_cert_details:
            subject: true
            cert: true
            chain: true
```

I can see the XFCC header with the cert values, but the certs are the ones passed on by Citadel for mTls and not the one that the client has sent in the header, which I am still looking at.